# Matching Regular expression any out of four

Tags: regex

I am new in regular expression.
I want to validate my password which must contains any three from below:

- One digit
- one Lower letter
- one Upper case Letter
- One special letter from this set of characters

  ```
  .~^;:?=@#${}|_()*,-
  ```

If any user enters One digit, One lower case letter, One Upper case letter and Special letter not from above group i.e `1234S%n&`, expression  should return false.

I have tried below expression :

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[.~^;:?=@#${}|_()*,-])(?!.*[+&%<>]).*$|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[.~^;:?=@#${}|_()*,-])(?!.*[&+%<>]).*$|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[.~^;:?=@#${}|_()*,-])(?!.*[&+%<>]).*$
```

Please help me to solve my confusion

Comment: __Ok. Good Luck.__ (_Please provide what you have tried_)

Comment: I have tried This Expression :(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[.~^;:?=@#${}|_()*,-])(?!.*[+&%<>]).*$|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[.~^;:?=@#${}|_()*,-])(?!.*[&+%<>]).*$|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[.~^;:?=@#${}|_()*,-])(?!.*[&+%<>]).*$

Comment: Please include it in the question then. (Otherwise people might downvote your question for lacking demonstration of effort)

Comment: What's not working in your regex? Why should `1234S%n&` return false, I'd say one digit one upper one lower make the 3 conditions you want. Or do you want *exactly* three conditions, meaning if there is one digit one lower one upper there can't be a special character from the list? Only digit/lower/upper/approved special allowed? Please, edit to add more info/test cases. (And please try to use the code formatting, it's really hard to read otherwise)

Comment: @Robin :Sorry, i will take care about formatting. I want to restrict user to enter special character out of group,means user enters special character in password then it must from group .

Comment: So you want only these approved characters, and at least 3 of the conditions you talked about. Do you have to do it in one regex?

Comment: @robin: Yes ,i want that and i want it in one regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match "at least n criteria, any of the following" is not very easy to do in a single regex.

I would recommend against it, and doing it in multiple steps (quick&dirty pseudo code):

```
password = "1234S%x"
i = 0

// only allowed characters are in the string
char_validated = password.find("^[a-zA-Z0-9.~^;:?=@#${}|_()*,-]+$") 

if password.find("[0-9]") then i++  // check for at least one digit
if password.find("[a-z]") then i++  // check for at least one lowercase
if password.find("[A-Z]") then i++  // check for at least one uppercase
if password.find("[.~^;:?=@#${}|_()*,-]") then i++  // check for at least one special

if (i>=3 && char_validated) then ok
```

---

If you *really* need to do it in one regex, you could use your refactored not-easy-on-the-eye regex:

```
^(?:(?=.*\d)(?:(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[.~^;:?=@#${}|_()*,-])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[.~^;:?=@#${}|_()*,-]))|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[.~^;:?=@#${}|_()*,-]))[a-zA-Z0-9.~^;:?=@#${}|_()*,-]+$
```

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/iW0zH0).

The idea is, instead of allowing anything after checking with lookaheads, to force the allowed characters with `[a-zA-Z0-9.~^;:?=@#${}|_()*,-]`

Comment: +1 There is no good reason to try and compress something like this into one indecipherable regex. Unless you add a ton of commenting, the next dev to come along will be completely unable to work out what on earth it is supposed to do, even with a tool like Expresso. Even with comments there's a good chance they'll be bamboozled. This way your code is self-documenting, clear and concise.